# Openlayers 5: Click event on specific layer?

Tags: openlayers

I have a couple of layers and i want to add click event on a specific layer of the map.

E.g. If clicking on parcels, do different ajax request than clicking on buildings.

How can i do it?

```
    var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: wmsSource
});
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [baseLayer, wmsLayer],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([33.33386, 35.14710]),
    zoom: 14
  })
});

map.on('click', function (evt) {
  map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (layer) {
    if (layer==='web:Parcels') {
      console.log('parcels clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you want to get from the layer? Generally, you can just loop over the layers, until you find your desired layer, but some functions (like map.forEachFeatureAtPixel) have a layerfilter-option

Comment: @Rob i'll click on the layer and get the degrees. It's important to click on the specific layer to request data from the server related to that layer.

Comment: How do you get the data from your server? Anyways, you can do forEachLayerAtPixel inside your click listener, and use the layerFilter-option there. You can get the Pixel from your evt. (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachLayerAtPixel)

Comment: @Rob i get the degrees on map click (should be on layer click) and i query data on the related layer table where `ST_CONTAINS(p.geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(33.3293679356575 35.144125764150516)'))` something like that

Comment: Since all layers of your map are in the same coordinate reference system, you will get the same (map) coordinates on every layer. However, you can convert map coordinates to geographic coordinates ('degrees') via ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate), or to any desired coordinateReferenceSystem via proj4

Comment: @Rob not sure if you understood what i want to do. See this photo: https://imgur.com/a/2YY6v4P. It has two layers buildings and parcels. If i click on the buildings i want to request data from another file (ajax). If i click on the parcel request from a different file. So i want to add click event based on the clicked layer.

Comment: Have you tried 'forEachLayerAtPixel', as posted above? This only works for Pixel, which have a color value (so it only fires for parcels, when you actually click on a parcel), so judging by your image, that's what you want. The layerFilter is described in the API-link above, it's a function that should return true if you got one of your layers, something like function(layer) {if(layer.name==='parcels'){return true}}. Here is the official example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html?q=foreachlayeratpixel

Answer (score 4):

You can add and retrieve extra attributes on a layer and aren't limited by key names. Here's a sample for OpenStreetMaps:

```
var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        id: 'base_osm',
        title: 'OpenStreetMap',
        group: 'base',
        whatever: 'Testing 123',
        visible: true,
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
})

map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(layer) {
        console.log(evt.pixel);
        console.log(layer);
        var id = layer.get('title');
        console.log(id);
        var title = layer.get('title');
        console.log(title);
        var whatever = layer.get('whatever');
        console.log(whatever);
    });
});
```

See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Base-BaseLayer.html#get for the API Doc on this.

That should plug right into a WMS example and a working fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/ategenkamp/Lhekcvna/3/ as well based on https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-tiled.html

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Hi, firstly, you have to close the function like that `});`. Secondly, i am getting the following error: `IntermediateCanvas.js:117 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.` Also you need map click event

Comment: I missed the }) from in copy/paste from the fiddle. That also has the click/singleclick event, which I added here. It was meant to be snippets like your original code but the fiddle puts it all together if needed.  The jsfiddle also has `crossOrigin: 'anonymous',` which you'll need in your source to fix the cross-origin data message.  There's a lot of stuff on CORS here if the server you get data from still has an issue.  I'm fighting with that myself for some of our sources myself!

Comment: So if one layer is above the other, and click on it, the click event will be triggered twice :/

Comment: The click event runs once but it loops through all visible layers and can run different code for each layer which seemed to be what you wanted in the original question.

Comment: The click event only runs once. It loops through each visible layer. You can run different code per layer which seems to answer your original question.